# platexで文字の置換

Tags: latex

LaTeXの文書中で（つまりエディタやコンパイル時に前処理などをしないで）文字を置換することを考えています。調べると、次のようなものが見つかりました。

- [`\newunicodechar`](https://ctan.org/pkg/newunicodechar)を用いる方法

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{newunicodechar}
  \newunicodechar{あ}{い}
  \begin{document}あ←「い」と出力させたい\end{document}
  ```

  次のエラーとなりました:

  ```
  Package newunicodechar Error: ASCII character requested.
  ```
- `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter`を用いる方法

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{3042}{い}
  \begin{document}あ←「い」と出力させたい\end{document}
  ```

  コンパイルはできましたが、置換が起きませんでした。

.texソースはutf8で書いています。これが原因であれば、sjis等にすることもできます。

何か実現する方法はないでしょうか。

コマンド:

```
> platex -shell-escape -file-line-error -halt-on-error -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 -kanji=utf8 test.tex
```

バージョン情報:

```
This is e-pTeX, Version 3.14159265-p3.8.2-190131-2.6 (utf8.sjis) (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX) (preloaded format=platex)
```

Comment: 文字の置換だけでしたら、`\def \あ{い}` を定義しておいて、`\あ←「い」と出力させたい` と書いておく(`あ`の直前にバックスラッシュを付ける)のはどうでしょう(一々バックスラッシュを付けるのは面倒かもしれませんが…)。

Comment: ひとまず，試された「\DeclareUnicodeCharacterを用いる方法」がうまくいかない理由についてですが，まさにマクロツイーター『単独の Unicode 文字を命令として扱う（newunicodechar パッケージ）』(https://zrbabbler.hatenablog.com/entry/20171126/1511670739) の「(u)pLaTeX で素敵な文字定義するときの注意」項に書かれている内容に該当しそうです：「newunicodechar パッケージは (u)pLaTeX でも一応使えるが少し制限がある。それは、『和文文字は命令扱いにできない』ということである。すなわち、定義対象の文字は欧文扱いになっている必要がある。」 お使いの pLaTeX では当然「和文文字は規定で和文扱い」なので，これを変更しないことにはうまく動かないでしょう．

Comment: @wtsnjp の説明はその通りで，これに補足すると，(1) まず，pLaTeX では和文文字を欧文扱いに，またその逆もできません。 (2) upLaTeX では \kcatcode プリミティブを使って和文扱いと欧文扱いを切替えることができますが，切替は Unicode のブロック単位なので，「あ」を欧文扱い（= UTF-8 のバイト列扱い）にしたら「い」も欧文扱い（= UTF-8 のバイト列扱い）に変わってしまいます。したがって，(1)(2) から，pLaTeX と upLaTeX では newunicodechar の仕組みで目的を達することはできないでしょう。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\newunicodechar` あるいは `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` は「欧文扱いされる文字」に対してだけ適用できる方法であり，「和文扱いされる文字」に対しては使えません。さらに言うと，和文文字を他の文字に置換することは，マクロレベルでは（少なくとも私は）不可能だと思います。

エディタで置換するのが最もたやすいと思いますが，「仮想フォント (VF; Virtual font) を作ってフォントの側で置換する」という方法を紹介します。ただし，下で使う makejvf というプログラムは，かなり新しいもの（TeX Live 2018 は可，2017 は不可）が必要です。

（技術的には pTeX の中・上級者レベルの話になります。また，特に「他の人とファイル交換する」ようなことがあれば，min10.vf が他人とは異なることも頭に入れておかないと，思わぬ事故の原因になります。）

---

以下，pLaTeX + dvipdfmx を使っていると仮定します。また，ご提示のファイルが `\documentclass{article}` で始まっているので，pLaTeX 標準の「min10」が使われていると仮定します（もし jsarticle クラスを使っていれば「min10」を「jis」に読み替えてください）。

まず，お使いの TeX システムから min10.tfm というファイルを探して，ソースと同じ場所に置いておいてください。次に，下記のファイルを a-to-i.cnf として同じ場所に保存します。

```
% パーセントで始まるものはコメント。
% REPLACE で置換前と置換後の文字コードを 16 進数で指定する。
% 「あ」は JIS で 0x2422，「い」は 0x2424
% 以下の行の空白はタブに置き換えてください。
REPLACE 2422 2424
```

ターミナル（Windows ならコマンドプロンプトや PowerShell）を起動し，ファイルが保存してある場所で以下のコマンドを実行します。

```
makejvf -t a-to-i.cnf min10 rml
```

すると，min10.vf と rml.tfm が得られるはずです（このうち min10.vf が文字「あ」を「い」に置換する情報を含むものです）。

出来たら，普段通り platex と dvipdfmx を実行してみてください。「あ」が「い」に置き換わっているはずです。

---

以下，注意点です。

- DVI ファイル自体は普通のものと同じです。dvipdfmx が「今回作った特殊な VF」を読み取って文字を置換します。
- そのため，本来「あ」が出力されようとする場所は全て「い」に置換されます。
- ゴシック体も置換したい場合は，コマンドの min10 を goth10 に置き換えたものを別途実行する必要があります。

Comment: 自分の環境でも動作させることができました！くわしい説明もしていただき、勉強になります。